# Can not wake Yongnuo flash with triggers after flash LCD panel sleeps

Tags: canon, flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

I have a YN-622C II trigger on top of a Canon 6D and another YN-622C II with a YN-565EX flash (off camera flash). After I turn everything on, and for the 15 seconds that the LCD panel of the flash is lit, I can change settings from the camera menu and fire the flash. But when the LCD panel of the flash goes off it loses communication, and I can no longer change settings from the camera, and the flash doesn´t fire either.

The flash is not set to sleep mode. What could the problem be? What am I missing? Is there a way to keep the LCD panel of the flash always lit?

Comment: When you say LCD goes off, do you mean nothing displays on the LCD, or that the backlight of the LCD turns off? In normal usage, the LCD should ALWAYS display all the settings. Do you see <SE> on the LCD? How is Custom Function 15 set?

Comment: SL EP is off , SE is off .....The LCD displays the settings at all time and everything works perfect until the backlight shuts off  and the flash does not communicates at all with the camera .

Answer (score 1):

From the YN565EX manual:

> **9. Power Saving Mode**
>
> YN565EX provides shrinkable power-saving mode; this power-saving mode
>   can set through long press on [Advanced option] button. Long press the
>   [Advanced option] to enter the setting state and select the option
>   with number 01 through [up] and [down] buttons. When pressing the
>   [right] button to set the state as SL EP - -, this means to disable
>   the function of “automatic power off”. When it is set as SL EP on,
>   this means that the function of “automatic power off” is enabled, the
>   following table lists the power-saving mode that is set through
>   advanced option.
>
> [image: YN565EX sleep Modes]

**EDIT:**

I recall an issue with YN565EX and sleep mode. Actually it wasn't a problem with the flash unit but with the camera going to sleep mode. Anyway, you may check [The Other YN-622C User Guide](http://www.westonphoto.plus.com/tutorials/TOYUG_v4-07.pdf). It has a lot of information regarding the use of those triggers.

Comment: Based on the information from the manual, none of the selected options should result in the behavior described in the question. Your answer fails to address the possibility that the flash unit is faulty or the possibility that there is another applicable setting elsewhere in the menu.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming the flash isn't faulty. I'm assuming the flash batteries have charge. I'm not assuming there are other options regarding sleep mode, because there aren't and the manual and my own experience with this particular model says so. I have three units of YN565Ex and any issue with sleep mode was solved via the menu settings. Sleep mode settings are maintained in the flash once turned off, but the right thing is to double check if the settings are the correct ones, and the OP don't mention exactly if the settings in his flash are these.

Comment: But the question says the flash is doing something that isn't indicated in the instructions you have quoted. You're not really answering the question. You're addressing how the flash *ought* to be acting and ignoring how the OP's flash *is* acting. For what it's worth, I've had Yongnuo flashes that did similar things before getting progressively more unpredictable and unreliable until they finally gave up the ghost.

Comment: "... and the OP don't mention exactly if the settings in his flash are these." The OP *did* say **"The flash is not set to sleep mode."**

Answer (score 0):

When the backlight that illuminates the flash's display panel goes dim, the settings should still be showing on the LCD panel as long as the flash is active. If they're not, then something is wrong with the flash. You can try shining a flashlight on the LCD panel after the backlight goes out and see if information is still being displayed (just without any self-illumination).

Although there is a setting available that tells the LCD backlight to turn off after about 15 seconds, there is no menu option that tells the flash to go into sleep mode after only 15 seconds. The shortest time selectable via the menu for the flash to go into sleep mode is after three minutes of idle time. If your flash is going into sleep mode or shutting off in less than three minutes with fully charged batteries installed then there is something wrong with your flash and it is not behaving as it is supposed to behave.

Yongnuo flashes have a less than rock solid reputation regarding reliability and longevity issues. I've had a couple that flaked out on me in different ways. They usually start by doing something odd here or there. A simple power cycle will usually solve the problem for a while until it reappears on an unpredictable intermittent basis. Then they'll start doing it more often and other unexpected behavior might manifest itself. This will get progressively worse until eventually they become unusable.

It's often the price one pays for going with cheap, third party flashes. If having a functional flash is critical for a shoot, I advise people to have at least one brand name flash made by the same manufacturer who made their camera. If additional flashes are needed, then third party units can be a good way to go as the cost savings are significant. Just always be prepared for one of them to die on you at the most inopportune time and always have one more flash than you need with you. It won't happen very often, but eventually it will happen.

Comment: So the OP asked a question regarding a particular model of flash + trigger and your answer is "buy a branded one" ? hilarious

Comment: I mentioned that only after first answering the question. Two paragraphs earlier than what you seem to think is the entirety of the answer I say: **"If your flash is going into sleep mode or shutting off in less than three minutes with fully charged batteries installed then there is something wrong with your flash and it is not behaving as it is supposed to behave."**

Comment: Thank you for answering everybody !   Michael Clark , where is the setting to leave the backlight always on...because that look to be the problem , which is very weird

Comment: @PabloPereyra The longest the backlight can be set to stay on for the YN565EX is for 30 seconds. You can do that via Advanced Options setting Fn No.:E3 Also confirm that Fn No.:E1 is set to "--" and Fn No.:01 is set to "--".

Comment: Here's a link to the User Manual: http://www.yongnuo.com.cn/usermanual/pdf/YN565EXIIforCanon_en_user_manual.pdf

Comment: @MichaelClark  Unfortunately my flash doesn´t have Fn No E3  and  E1 .....so I guess I´m screwed  , I will try to borrow a pair of the same triggers I have and see if the problem is the flash or the triggers . thanks everybody for your help , I will post back when I find what the problem was

Comment: Do you have a YN565EX or a YN565EX II. That's two different flashes.